# Bootstrap 4 Alpha and upgrading

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap 4 is to be released sometime in 2016.

What's the best approach to upgrade - a complete re-write? I did that for Boostrap 2 to 3 and not sure if I can face that again for version 4....

Thanks

Comment: Bootstrap 4 is planned to be an easier migration, and there are [update tools available](http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com).

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap 4 is still in early alpha and lacks some key fetures.
The framework might also be changed very radically with every new release, so maintaining that can be very painful.

You can still use Bootstrap 3, which will be supported officialy even after v4's final release:

> For the foreseeable future, we’ll be maintaining Bootstrap 3 with critical bug fixes and documentation improvements. v3 docs will also continue to be hosted after v4’s final release.

(From [the Bootstrap blog](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2015/08/19/bootstrap-4-alpha/))

Also note that even if you want to go on this adventurous way, you should never use alpha or beta code in production.

Comment: I happened upon this article and note that Bootstrap no longer support version 3. Even though version 4 is still in Alpha.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @eburger 's answer. If you start developing now, make sure you can update bootstrap after your changes and modifications. Use Bootstrap's Grunt build tool Running the autoprefixer is required.

Create Sass partials for your modifications (one for the SCSS and one for your custom variables), import these files into `bootstrap.scss` (of the source code). You can use bower to keep bootstrap's code uptodate. Bootstrap uses many predefined CSS classes, these classes may change after new releases, then you will have to update your HTML too.

Notice that you should **never** use alpha or beta code for production.

I have already built some tools to test Bootstrap 4; if that's what you're looking for:

- https://github.com/bassjobsen/generator-bootstrap4
- https://github.com/bassjobsen/brunch-bootstrap4
- https://github.com/bassjobsen/jbst-4-sass

Comment: "Notice that you should never use alpha or beta code for production."

That is simply not true, bet many Angular2 projects are in production for instance. And I haven`t noticed any problems running Bootstrap 4 alpha since 2015.

Comment: @David I disagree. Alpha and beta releases are not recommended for production use by authors themselves (that's what they are for) - and who else can know better than them? If you haven't noticed any problems using Bootstrap alpha, it doesn't mean there aren't any. It's generally wrong idea to rely on framework/library before authors release a stable version.

Comment: @cuddlecheek What I say is that you're statement that you should never use beta for production, is wrong.
As example in Angular2 beta  they clearly stated it was production ready, and like you said "Who knows better than the authors".
Most projects are also in production while they are being developed, it can then be smart to go for a version that are in beta so that when the project is finished, the framework is in release version as well. So  you don't have to rewrite you`re code to support the new versions, which can be a really big job, like Angular 1 -> 2.

Comment: "Most projects are also in production while they are being developed, it can then be smart to go for a version that are in beta so that when the project is finished, the framework is in release version as well" -> this is not **using beta in production**. Using beta in production means you are using beta **at the time of your release**, so when you develop with beta but release the project (or update) after the framework is declared stable, it's not the case.
I would also like to see Angular documentation saying their beta is production ready. Sounds like oxymoron to me.